# zless exits when reaching EOF

Tags: terminal, command-line

I run the command

```
zless some.log
```

in OS X 10.11.5 El Capitan.

It closes when reaching EOF.

I checked aliases and I do not have LESS env variable set up but still it looks like `zless` runs with `-Q` or `-q` parameter on.

`less` command runs just as expected not closing after reaching EOF.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

zless/zmore will use /usr/bin/more as the default PAGER unless PAGER is set. Add the following lines to your shell login/env file (bash, ksh, and zsh).

```
PAGER=/usr/bin/less
export PAGER
```

For tcsh:

```
setenv PAGER /usr/bin/less
```